# Listener Null Object Reference

Tags: android

my onAttach() method assigns the context to the listener, however, my listener is null somehow. How can I fix this problem properly? I hope you can provide me the code with some instructions?

ChooseScreen class **which initializes the dialog** (In this case nameDialog):

```
public class ChooseScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button vsFriend;
private Button vsAndroid;
private NameDialog.NameDialogListener listener;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_choose_screen);
    vsFriend = findViewById(R.id.vsF);
    vsAndroid = findViewById(R.id.vsA);

    vsFriend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openDialog();
        }
    });
}

public void openDialog() {
    NameDialog nameDialog = new NameDialog();
    nameDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "example");

}

}
```

NameDialog class with getTexts interface:

```
public class NameDialog extends AppCompatDialogFragment  {
private EditText firstPlayer;
private EditText secondPlayer;
private NameDialogListener listener;


@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_dialog, null);

    firstPlayer = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_player1);
    secondPlayer = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_player2);

    builder.setView(view)
            .setTitle("Names")
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            })
            .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    String player1 = firstPlayer.getText().toString();
                    String player2 = secondPlayer.getText().toString();
                    listener.getTexts(player1, player2);
                    // Intent intent = new Intent(NameDialog.this.getActivity(), Game.class);
                    // startActivity(intent);
                }
            });

    return builder.create();
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
        try{
        listener = (NameDialogListener) context;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + "must implement");
        }
}

public interface NameDialogListener {
    void getTexts(String player1, String player2);
}
}
```

Game class which implements NameDialogListener and overrides the interface method(getTexts):

```
public class Game extends AppCompatActivity implements 
NameDialog.NameDialogListener {
private TextView player1Name;
private TextView player2Name;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
    player1Name = findViewById(R.id.player1TextView);
    player2Name = findViewById(R.id.player2TextView);
}

@Override
public void getTexts(String player1, String player2) {
    player1Name.setText(player1);
    player2Name.setText(player2);
}

}
```

Error: If I don't use try-catch block, the error will be NullPointerException because listener is null!

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.user.tictactoe, PID: 30462
                  java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.user.tictactoe.ChooseScreen@1a0a489must implement
                      at com.example.user.tictactoe.NameDialog.onAttach(NameDialog.java:62)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1372)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1759)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1827)
                      at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:797)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2596)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2383)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2338)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2245)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:703)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1518)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you attach your Fragment you attempt to get a Listener from your ChoooseScreen `Activity`. That `Activity` does not implement `NameDialogListener`, so you get a ClassCastException. In your examples you show another `Activity`, Game that does implement the listener, however any activity you add your `Fragment` in will need to implement the listener to work with your `onAttach()` code.

Short answer: if you want to show the `Fragment` in `ChooseScreen`, your code requires `ChooseScreen` to implement `NameDialogListener`.

Comment: Your ClassCastException is thrown by your `Fragment` with this line:
`throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + "must implement");`

Comment: I've implemented NameDialogListener and there is no error anymore, however, I need to get values from dialog panel and show them in Game class. ChooseScreen implements NameDialogListener, so I override the getTexts, also my Game class implements the same interface and overrides the same method. I think the interface method I override in Game class doesn't work. Probably this line is never executed. I cannot see the values from the dialog panel in my game activity.

Comment: How do you navigate in app from `ChooseScreen` to `Game`? You get the results in the activity you show the `Fragment` in, so if further down the workflow you need to pass those results to another `Activity` you should send them via extras on your `Intent` or have some other method for saving that data and then retrieving it when you change `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

onAttach will get the context of your parent activity. when you open your Dialog from ChooseScreen activity, the parent is ChooseScreen. The interface callback will be given to ChooseScreen itself. Then what you need to do is to call Intent with player1Name and player2Name.

Anyways I will share the code for you.

Your ChooseScreen

```
public class ChooseScreen extends AppCompatActivity implements NameDialog.NameDialogListener {
    private Button vsFriend;
    private Button vsAndroid;
    private NameDialog.NameDialogListener listener;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_choose_screen);
        vsFriend = findViewById(R.id.vsF);
        vsAndroid = findViewById(R.id.vsA);

        vsFriend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openDialog();
            }
        });
    }

    public void openDialog() {
        NameDialog nameDialog = new NameDialog();
        nameDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "example");

    }

    @Override
    public void getTexts(String player1, String player2) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Game.class);
        intent.putExtra("PLAYER_ONE", player1);
        intent.putExtra("PLAYER_TWO", player2);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Your NameDialog

```
public class NameDialog extends AppCompatDialogFragment {
    private EditText firstPlayer;
    private EditText secondPlayer;
    private NameDialogListener listener;


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_dialog, null);

        firstPlayer = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_player1);
        secondPlayer = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_player2);

        builder.setView(view)
                .setTitle("Names")
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    }
                })
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        String player1 = firstPlayer.getText().toString();
                        String player2 = secondPlayer.getText().toString();
                        listener.getTexts(player1, player2);

                        //TODO you can simply use below code and comment listener.getTexts();
//                        Intent intent = new Intent(NameDialog.this.getActivity(), Game.class);
//                        intent.putExtra("PLAYER_ONE", player1);
//                        intent.putExtra("PLAYER_TWO", player2);
//                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

        return builder.create();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try {
            listener = (NameDialogListener) context;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + "must implement");
        }
    }

    public interface NameDialogListener {
        void getTexts(String player1, String player2);
    }
}
```

Your Game

```
public class Game extends AppCompatActivity
       /* implements NameDialog.NameDialogListener*/ {
    private TextView player1Name;
    private TextView player2Name;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
        player1Name = findViewById(R.id.player1TextView);
        player2Name = findViewById(R.id.player2TextView);

        player1Name.setText(
                getIntent().getStringExtra("PLAYER_ONE"));
        player2Name.setText(
                getIntent().getStringExtra("PLAYER_TWO"));
    }

//    @Override
//    public void getTexts(String player1, String player2) {
//    }

}
```

Try this and let me know...